# How to make GitLab's CI/CD job fail based on text in console output?

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, lerna

I am using [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) to manage a multipackage repository and in my deployment job I use Lerna's `publish` command. For me if code is changed in a package it should always publish a new version to our Artifactory and fail the job if nothing was published, but the `publish` command will exit with success code (I guess it's 0 code) even when no packages where published:

```
$ npx lerna publish from-package --yes

lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info ci enabled
lerna notice from-package No unpublished release found
lerna success No changed packages to publish 
Job succeeded
```

I was thinking I could workaround this by piping the output to GREP and searching for the text `"No changed packages to publish"` but then not sure how to tell Gitlab to make the job fail when that text is found.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are calling `npx` in a bash script, you can catch the text and exit with non-0 status:

```sh
lerna_output=$(npx lerna publish from-package --yes) || exit $?
nothing_published=$(echo $lerna_output | grep 'No changed packages to publish')
if [ "$nothing_published" != "" ]; then
    echo $lerna_output
    exit 1
fi
```