# Fail Gitlab pipeline based on output

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using a docker container ([sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze)) in a Gitlab pipeline for some testing. This pipeline always succeeds, but I would like the pipeline to fail if the container ever reported a "FAIL" in its output. Currently if a "FAIL" is reported  in the terminal output, an exit code of 0 is still reported (as the scan itself worked) so Gitlab passes the pipeline.

I am new to Gitlab, but familiar with Jenkins, and in Jenkins you could fail the job based on the terminal output using [Text Finder](https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder/). Is there a similar concept in Gitlab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make GitLab's CI/CD job fail based on text in console output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57416222/how-to-make-gitlabs-ci-cd-job-fail-based-on-text-in-console-output)

Comment: @secustor Thank you, similar enough to provide some help, have posted my solution below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @secustor in the comments for pointing me to a similar question. I was hoping for some native functionality within Gitlab but I couldn't find any.

Instead, I queried the container logs and the exit code, then set an exit code of 1 depending on the outcome.

Within in an .gitlab-ci.yml (I had problems splitting the logic across multiple lines so it's all jammed into one line):

```
  script:
  - docker run --name containername nablac0d3/sslyze --regular $URL
  - if [[ "$(docker logs containername >& container-logs ; cat container-logs | grep 'FAIL' | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]] || [[ "$(docker container wait containername)" -eq 1 ]]; then exit 1; fi
```